# Two buttons one window

Tags: c++, qt

I've got two push_buttons on dialog and both of them are meant to invoke QFileDialog window, with the difference that first button is for input files and second for output files, other than that logic is the same. What is the best way to connect those buttons to QFileDialog without doing any code repetion.

P.S.
Ideally those two windows (Open File) would have different titles.

Comment: I hope no one is entertained by your title, seems pretty forced (readers: if you don't catch the reference, just keep moving...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO you should use two QFileDialog objects, one for each case. To make a difference between imput/output you should set the [AcceptMode](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfiledialog.html#AcceptMode-enum).

Comment: I'm ok with using two different QFileDialog objs but what I'm trying to do is to avoid code repetions. Because except QFileDialog obj rest of the code is identicall.

Comment: Move all the code from one of the button handlers to a function. Add to the function's signature the parameters that differ (for example: the QFileDialog object and whatever data you require for that case) and call instead in each of the handlers that function.